# Receiving failure notice after recalling a message, even the recipient was not in online

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Receiving failure notice after recalling a message, even the recipient was not online. 
Please help me to find what settings would have been done on the recipient's side.

Answer (score 0):

"Recalling a message" is a feature of the Exchange server, not a standard. If the recipient is not using such, but anything else, you cannot "recall" the message. I'm not even sure whether it could be done if the recipient is connected to a different Exchange server than you are.